# CURL with port and additional parameters in URL, JSON parsing

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a URL in the form of `http://www.domain.com:10001/api/Data.cgi?Scope=System`

On that URL is a JSON dump which I need to parse. How do I access it? I've used `get_file_contents` before which is why I am struggling with this - first occasion to have a port on the URL. It would be best if I could grab the JSON and put it in a file.txt and then parse the file.

```
<?php
$cURL = curl_init('http://81.1.1.1'); 
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_PORT, 10001); 
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

$fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

I'm not sure how to properly add the remainder of the URL.

Comment: You're asking two questions really, first how to get the file contents with CURL, then next how to parse the JSON, right?

It'd be easier to use file_get_contents to get the contents, and json_decode to parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to use curl, it may be easier with file_get_contents.

```
// Retrieve file
$data = file_get_contents("http://81.1.1.1:10001/page_url.json?query_parameters=values");

// Echo retrieved file
echo $data;

// Decode JSON
$decoded = json_decode($data);

// Dump decoded data
var_dump($decoded);
```

Comment: hi @Ross - Is it possible to use `file_get_contents` on a URL with a port on it? As I get no response...so perhaps it's the server I'm grabbing the info from the issue? How could I verify this?

Comment: It is possible to use a port number with file_get_contents.  Turn on error reporting to see if you're getting any errors, make sure no firewall rules are blocking the request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    function curl($url) {

            $options = Array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE, 
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,  
                CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE

, 
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,  
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8",  
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,

        );

        $ch = curl_init();  // Initialising cURL

        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);   

        $data = curl_exec($ch); 

        curl_close($ch);    

        return $data;   
    }

    $scraped_page = curl($link);
```

Comment: So my code now looks like this - https://codeshare.io/lk9CR but still not working...any ideas?